# How to Override Select.phtml (product/view/options/type/select.phtml) magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides

How to Override Select.phtml (product/view/options/type/select.phtml) magento 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.form.options.select" template="Maxime_Helloworld::select.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: have you created a theme?

Answer (score 2):

Just set file inside your default theme,

```
app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/options/type/select.phtml
```

Comment: How can use module

Comment: Above way's using override in theme.

Comment: Try with override full catalog_product_view.xml file into your module and set template for select.phtml file.

Comment: How to override *catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/text.phtml* in EE M2.2.0?

Answer (score 2):

Create **catalog_product_view.xml** at

> /app/code/Maxime/Helloworld/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
                <referenceBlock name="product.info.options">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="Maxime_Helloworld::select.phtml"/>
                </referenceBlock>
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create **select.phtml** at

> /app/code/Maxime/Helloworld/view/frontend/templates/select.phtml

Comment: This is not working in Magento 2.1.17.